# Поиск слова в предложении

Tags: регулярные-выражения, boost, c++

У меня не получается осуществить поиск слова "the" в строке: "reading the text file". Пытаюсь это сделать так:

```
 string reg_str = "reading the text file";
 boost::regex xRegEx("(\bthe\b)");
 if(boost::regex_search(reg_str.begin(), reg_str.end(), xRegEx))
 {
   cout << "Yes" << endl;
 }
```

Данное регулярное выражение должно работать согласно [данному](http://regex101.com/r/rD4hR1) ресурсу.
Что я не так делаю?

Comment: Зачем вы экранируете слеш перед \b?

Конструкция \b означает границу слова

Comment: Убрал экранирование - все равно не работает. \b использую чтобы высвечивались "the." "the?" и т.п.

Comment: @derkode, правильный подход, это не регэкспы, а синтаксический разбор текста.

Comment: Могу конечно ошибаться, но не является ли \b (вроде символ забоя или как там он правильно называется) эскейп последовательностью в плюсах?

Comment: скомпилировал у себя - все прекрасно работает и компилирует.

gcc 4.8.2 / clang 3.4 + boost 1.54 / linux

экранирование нужно - это специфика с++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если задача найти слово в предложении, то может так

```
string reg_str = "reading the text file";
string::size_type loc = reg_str.find( "the", 0 );
if( loc != string::npos ) {
   cout << "Yes" << endl;
 } else {
   cout << "No" << endl;
 }
```

UPD

С регулярными выражениями можно так

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string reg_str = "reading the text file";
    boost::regex xRegEx("([^\\w\\d]the[^\\w\\d])");
    if(boost::regex_search(reg_str.begin(), reg_str.end(), xRegEx))
    {
            cout << "Yes" << endl;
    }
    cout<< "Finished" <<endl;
}
```

Comment: Это работает на половину, т.к. осуществляется поиск последовательности букв. Если исходная строка будет к примеру then, то код выдаст положительный ответ, но это не правильно. Нужно искать слово отдельно.

Comment: Обновил для работы с регулярными выражениями

Answer (score 0):

http://regex101.com/r/bP6wS8 так тоже ничего не ищет? Если да, то, наверное диалект не поддерживает такие метапоследовательности, ищите доки по регуляркам в с++ boost